# Get a key: value pair dictionary from two consecutive columns of pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, dictionary

I am extracting data from excel sheet and storing it into a dataframe. I want to create a key:value pair dictionary from the columns of dataframe.

For example: `[{key=column1 : value = column2, key = column3 : value=column4 }]`, and so on till the last column.
Here is the sample data on which I am working: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrurH.png

I am aware of the logic, `df.set_index('column1').T.to_dict('records')[0]` 
but this logic does not work for me since I want to get the key:value pair of every two consecutive columns.

expected result:

```
[{column1.value:column2.value, column3.value:column4.value, column5.value:column6.value}]
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: So you want a separate dictionary for each row? Or just one dictionary for the entire DataFrame?

Comment: Hi Alloz, thanks for your quick response. I want one dictionary for the entire dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, try this:

Setup dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1':[*'ABC'],
                   'Column2':[5,10,15],
                   'Column3':[*'DEF'],
                   'Column4':[20,25,30],
                   'Column5':[*'GHI'],
                   'Column6':[35,40,45]})
```

Use `reshape`, `set_index`, and `to_dict`:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(-1,2)).set_index(0).to_dict(orient='dict')[1]
```

Output:

```
{'A': 5,
 'D': 20,
 'G': 35,
 'B': 10,
 'E': 25,
 'H': 40,
 'C': 15,
 'F': 30,
 'I': 45}
```

Comment: @PriyankaLanjewar Would you mind [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) this  answer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can slice even and odd columns with `::2` and `1::2`

```
dict(zip(df.iloc[:, ::2].to_numpy().ravel(), df.iloc[:, 1::2].to_numpy().ravel()))
```

#### Output:

```
{'A': 5,
 'B': 10,
 'C': 15,
 'D': 20,
 'E': 25,
 'F': 30,
 'G': 35,
 'H': 40,
 'I': 45}
```

Or if one per row:

```
[dict(zip(x[0].tolist(), x[1].tolist())) for x in zip(df.iloc[:, ::2].to_numpy(), df.iloc[:, 1::2].to_numpy())]
#[{'A': 5, 'D': 20, 'G': 35},
# {'B': 10, 'E': 25, 'H': 40},
# {'C': 15, 'F': 30, 'I': 45}]
```

Comment: I need to remember to use to_numpy instead of .values.